# Programs similar to iPhoto or Picasa with geotagging?

Tags: windows, photography

I recently asked a question on Ask Different and it led to me to the discovery of Picasa. Admittedly, iPhoto would've been much better, but I have a Windows laptop. Anyways, the only feature that I'm looking for is the geotagging feature. Picasa can do that but it's pretty lame. You can only do one picture at a time and it gives you latitudes and longitudes and an option for a map that you can open, but only on every individual picture. Is there any other program that has an interface that's more similar to the one on your iPhone? Where it can show you all the pictures in all of the locations at once, and once you zoom in the locations branch out?

Answer (score 2):

There is [Pictmo](http://www.pictomio.com/) with the geotag extension it is freeware, (but still copyrighted), for Windows. And is probably worth a try.

[image: Image1][image: Image2]